# Nginx http2_push issue

Tags: nginx, openssl, http2

I am trying to implement `http2_push` using `nginx` on windows 7. I followed steps mentioned in [**this article**](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/).

I'm running `nginx 1.13.12` executable version. Have created & installed self signed certificates and it is working fine.

As mentioned in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530846/http2-push-with-nginx), I checked and solved the certificate validation issue as well.

Still the files I want to push is not getting pushed into the browser. I am checking it through the network tab in inspector (Google Chrome - Screenshot attached).

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      ssl/localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  ssl/localhost.key;

        location = /test.html {
            root html;
            http2_push /stylepush.css;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output (Screenshot):**

[image]

Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is stylepush.css in the same directory as test.html?

Comment: @FaisalMemon Yes its in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP/2 push only works when the pushed resource is needed by the page (i.e. it's referenced in the HTML). In this case, the fact that `/stylepush.css` is not loaded by the page at all (never mind by Push as the initiator) shows it is not being used.

If you go to `chrome://net-internals/#http2` you should see this as an unclaimed push:

[image]

Add a reference to this CSS file in your HTML and you should see it as pushed.

[image]

If not, then go to `chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:HTTP2_SESSION` in Chrome and provide the HTTP/2 Session data.

Additionally Chrome requires a recognised certificate before it allows you to cache resources (and HTTP/2 resources are pushed into a cache before they are uses). [Since Chrome Version 58, they also require the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) to be be set on the certificate](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4981025180483584), which requires some [extra config to set when creating a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665243/invalid-self-signed-ssl-cert-subject-alternative-name-missing).

Comment: Any specific way to add a reference or simply a `link` tag are you talking about?

Comment: You must add a `<link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“/stykepush.css”>` tag to your HTML so the page tries to load the CSS file.

Comment: I added `link` tag but then the Initiator for the `stylepush.css` is showing `test.html` and not `Push/test.html` [Check Screenshot](http://kapadiapankit.in/ss.jpg)

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of chrome://net-internals/#http2 ? And ideally the log contents for your domain in chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type&type:HTTP2_SESSION

Comment: Here are the screenshots: [HTTP2](http://kapadiapankit.in/http2.jpg) & [Events](http://kapadiapankit.in/event.jpg).

Comment: What I am noticing is when I use/add `link` tag in my html, the net-internal is showing `Duplicate pushed stream with url: https://localhost/stylepush.css` in `HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_RST_STREAM` block.

Comment: So push is working from nginx but Chrome is refusing it. That's usually due to a certificate error. Is your certificate for localhost? Or Localhost? Or LOCALHOST? I've seen instances in those cases where your see a green padlock but it's not accepted as a valid cert for HTTP/2.

Comment: Can you show the Subject Alternative Name for the Certificate under the Details tab?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://kapadiapankit.in/crt-sub.jpg)? I could not find `Alternative Name` thing.

Comment: That;'s your problem then but Chrome shouldn't accept that and you should not have a green padlock. Did you get a cert error when you go to the site? What version of chrome are you on?

Comment: Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181. No I didn't get any cert error. How do I create self sign certificate which has `Alternative Name`? I'd created it using openssl.

Comment: Sharing you the commands which I'd used creating the certificates. [Check this](http://kapadiapankit.in/ssl.jpg)

Comment: Weird. there are plenty of resources on creating certificates with Subject Alternative Names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665243/invalid-self-signed-ssl-cert-subject-alternative-name-missing

Comment: Okay Thanks. I will check and regenerate certificate which has Subject Alternative Name. Get back to you after a trial :)

Comment: Finally! Yes, after adding Subject Alternative Name to the certificate it worked like a charm! :) Thanks a lot for you support. I have one more doubt. When I include `link` tag in my html file. Won't it be increasing the number of requests to the server?

Comment: The browser will see the link, see it needs the stylesheet, and then realise it already has it cause it’s already been pushed. I can recommend a good book on this subject btw :-) https://www.manning.com/books/http2-in-action

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot Barry! :)